# Join large set of CSV files where the header is the timestamp for the file

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I have a large set of CSV files. Approx. 15 000 files. And would like to figure out how to join them together as one file for data processing.

Each file is in a simple pattern with timestamp that corresponds to a period of time that represent the data in the each CSV file.

Ex.

file1.csv

```
2021-07-23 08:00:00
Unit.Device.No03.ErrorCode;11122233
Unit.Device.No04.ErrorCode;0
Unit.Device.No05.ErrorCode;0
Unit.Device.No11.ErrorCode;0
```

file2.csv

```
2021-07-23 08:15:00
Unit.Device.No03.ErrorCode;0
Unit.Device.No04.ErrorCode;44556666
Unit.Device.No05.ErrorCode;0
Unit.Device.No11.ErrorCode;0
```

Each file starts with the timestamp. I would like to join all the files in a directory, and transpose the "Unit.Device" to columns. And then use the original header as a timestamp column. For each file add a new row with the corresponding "ErrorCode" to each column.

Like this:

```
Timestamp;Unit.Device.No03.ErrorCode;Unit.Device.No04.ErrorCode;Unit.Device.No05.ErrorCode..
2021-07-23 08:00:00;11122233;0;0;0;0....
2021-07-23 08:15:00;0;44556666;0;0;0....
```

Any simple tools for this, or Python routines?

Comment: The input files you have are not in a valid CSV format, so you will need to handle reading them yourself or do something to get existing tools to accept them. That said, Python has a [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module for reading and writing CSV format files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Pandas approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

dfs = []

for csv_filename in glob.glob('./file*.csv'):
    print('Working on file', csv_filename)
    # Read the CSV file, assume no header and two columns
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, sep=';', names=[0, 1], header=None)
    # Transpose from the 2nd row (skip the timestamp)
    df_transposed = df[1:].T
    # Allocate the column names from the first row and 'Timestamp'
    df_transposed.columns = df_transposed.iloc[0] + 'Timestamp'
    # Copy the timestamp into the transposed dataframe as a datetime value
    df_transposed['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0, 0])
    # Remove the first row (containing the names)
    df_transposed = df_transposed[1:]
    dfs.append(df_transposed)

# Concatenate all dataframes together and sort by Timestamp
df_output = pd.concat(dfs).sort_values(by='Timestamp')
# Sort the header columns and output to a CSV file
df_output.reindex(sorted(df_output.columns), axis=1).to_csv('output.csv', index=None)
```

---

Alternatively, it could be done using standard Python:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import glob

data = []
fieldnames = set()

for fn in glob.glob('file*.csv'):
    with open(fn) as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=';')
        timestamp = next(csv_input)[0]
        row = {'Timestamp' : timestamp}
        
        for device, error_code in csv_input:
            row[device] = error_code
            fieldnames.add(device)
            
        data.append(row)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=['Timestamp', *sorted(fieldnames)], delimiter=';')
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(sorted(data, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['Timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

This gives `output.csv` as:

```
Timestamp;Unit.Device.No03.ErrorCode;Unit.Device.No04.ErrorCode;Unit.Device.No05.ErrorCode;Unit.Device.No11.ErrorCode
2021-07-23 08:00:00;11122233;0;0;0
2021-07-23 08:15:00;0;44556666;0;0
```

How does this work

1. First iterate over all `.csv` files in a given folder.
2. For each file open it using a `csv.reader()`
3. Read the header row as a special case, storing the value as a `Timestamp` entry in a dictionary row.
4. For each row, store additional key value entries in the row dictionary.
5. Keep a note of each device name using a set.
6. Append the complete row into a `data` list.
7. It is now possible to create an `output.csv` file. The full list of columns names can be assigned as `fieldnames` and a `csv.DictWriter()` used.
8. Write the header.
9. Use `writerows()` to write all the `data` rows sorted by timestamp. To do this convert each row's `Timestamp` entry into a datetime value for sorting.

This approach will also work if the CSV files happen to have different types of devices e.g. `Unit.Device.No42.ErrorCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply on my first question here!
I will also contribute with a solution for this problem.

I did some read up on Pandas after I found something similar to what I wanted to do. I found that the transform method was very easy to use, and put together this snippet of Python code instead.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

folder = 'in'

df_out = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in os.scandir(folder):
    if filename.is_file():
        print('Working on file' + filename.path)

        df = pd.read_csv(filename.path, encoding='utf-16', sep=';',header =[0])

        # Transpose data with timestamp header to columns
        df_tranposed = df.T
        df_out = df_out.append(df_tranposed)


df_out.to_csv('output.csv')
```